# Why is my code only reading the first column of numbers in the .txt file in java

Tags: java, arrays, multidimensional-array, java-io

I am trying to read a .txt file into two different arrays one 1d string array and one 2d int array.  The code reads the names into the NamesArray just fine.  However, the code seems to either only read the first column of numbers in or only outputs the first column.  I'm not sure where I'm going wrong with the code.  Any help is greatly appreciated!

The data below is how it is formatted in the file.

```
Jason 10 15 20 25 18 20 26  
Samantha 15 18 29 16 26 20 23  
Ravi 20 26 18 29 10 12 20  
Sheila 17 20 15 26 18 25 12  
Ankit 16 8 28 20 11 25 21
```

Here is the code that I have so far.

```
import java.io.*;
import java.util.*;

public class Page636Exercise12
{
//      static Scanner console = new Scanner(System.in); 

    public static void main(String[] args) throws FileNotFoundException, IOException
    {                                                              
        int Count = 0;

        String[] NamesArray = new String[5];
        int [][] MileageArray = new int [5][7];

        int Mileage = 0;
        String Names = "";

        //Open the input file.
        Scanner inFile = new Scanner(new FileReader("Ch9_Ex12Data.txt"));

        //Reads from file into NamesArray and MileageArray.
        while (inFile.hasNext())
        {
             Names = inFile.next();
             NamesArray[Count] = Names;
             Mileage = inFile.nextInt();
             MileageArray[Count][Count] = Mileage;
             Names = inFile.nextLine();

             System.out.println(NamesArray[Count] + " " + MileageArray[Count][Count]);                
            Count++;           
           inFile.close();           
    }
}
```

Here is what I get for the output.

```
Jason 10  
Samantha 15  
Ravi 20  
Sheila 17  
Ankit 16
```

Comment: Take care of Java naming conventions. Variable names should start with lower case character

Comment: You are only getting the first number since you only stored the first one `Scanner.nextInt()` gets the next **token** which are often delimited by whitespaces (I assume they are in your file).

Comment: You can also try reading lines, separating string by space( ' ' ), the first element will always be the name rest would be numbers. It would make your code more flexible as even if the number of numbers varies it would still work.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem is that you are only storing one number in the `MileageArray` at index `[count][count]`. You will need to populate the array with a loop that loops for the total number of integer tokens expected like so:

```
for(int j = 0; j < 7; j++){
    Mileage = inFile.nextInt();
    MileageArray[Count][j] = Mileage;
}
Names = inFile.nextLine();
```

I'd also suggest that you specify the `MileageArray` column and row size as constants. i.e.:

```
final int ROWS = 5;
final int COLS = 7;
```

This will allow you to update your parsing code in a more configurable way if the input file format changes.

Comment: Sorry to say that but this solution is not really a solution to the issue. Think about what you suggest `inFile.nextInt()` is outside the loop so the value stored in `Mileage` will be the same for every iteration, so basicly you are storing 7 times the first number scanned and parsed ;)

Comment: You are correct. The sample has been updated to reflect this.

Answer (score 0):

You are reading only the first int number

```
Mileage = inFile.nextInt();
```

You need an inner loop to run 7 times to read all integers and add them in 2D array.

Answer (score 0):

The answer is simple, what you do by invoking `Mileage = inFile.nextInt()` you get the next token of the input line you are currently at and parse it to an `int` but since the numbers are delimited by something (assumed a whitespace) only the first number is read and parsed.
You have multiple options to fix this. You can either:

**Solution 1**

[Sparkplug were quicker than me.](https://stackoverflow.com/a/49665661/8181750)

**Solution 2**

```
try (BufferedReader br = new BufferedReader(
        new FileReader( new File( "Performance_Results_310_13.dat" ) ) ))
    {
      String line;
      while ( (line = br.readLine()) != null )
      {
        // split everything in a temporary array
        String[] temp = line.split( "\\s" );
        // the name will always at the first position rest of the line are the numbers
        name = temp[ 0 ];
        nameArray[ count ] = name;
        // or just simply nameArray[count] = temp[0]
        // start at 1 since 0 is the name
        for ( int i = 1; i < temp.length - 1; i++ )
        {
          // create a new array which is big enough for all numbers following
          mileageArray[count] = new int[temp.length - 1];
          mileageArray[ count ][ i - 1 ] = Integer.parseInt( temp[ i ] );
        }
        count++;
      }
    }
    catch ( IOException e )
    {
      e.printStackTrace();
    }
```

This solution reads the entire line and then parses it into the desired format. It is a bit more flexible in my opinion but you must assure that the arrays are big enough to store the data. Also note that this solution does only work if every token after a whitespace is parsable to an `int` except for the first one.

Answer (score 0):

You need to take two variable to travel a two dimensional array and at the same time print it. You can use below code it works as expected.

```
public static void main(String[] args) throws FileNotFoundException, IOException{
            int count = 0;
            int j = 0;
            String[] NamesArray = new String[5];
            int[][] MileageArray = new int[5][7];

            int Mileage = 0;
            String Names = "";

            // Open the input file.
            Scanner inFile = new Scanner(new FileReader("Ch9_Ex12Data.txt"));

            // Reads from file into NamesArray and MileageArray.
            while (inFile.hasNext()) {
                Names = inFile.next();
                NamesArray[count] = Names;
                j = 0;
                System.out.print(NamesArray[count]);
                while (inFile.hasNextInt())
                {
                    Mileage = inFile.nextInt();
                    MileageArray[count][j] = Mileage;
                    System.out.print(" "+MileageArray[i][j]);
                    j++;
                }

                Names = inFile.nextLine();
                count++;
                System.out.println("");
            }
            inFile.close();
        }
```